# ASMX WebService and use of List Object

Tags: 2010, asp.net

I have developed WCF service in Visual Studio 2010 and following is the code which worked perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace OracleEmpService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public List<Employee> getEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            string connectionString = "Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;" +
                   "User ID=scott;Password=ABC54321;Unicode=True";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql;
                sql = "SELECT * FROM Emp where rownum<=100000";
                command.CommandText = sql;
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.Employee_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmpNo"]);
                    employee.Employee_Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Ename"]);
                    employee.Employee_Job = Convert.ToString(reader["Job"]);
                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
                return employees.ToList();
            }
        }
        public Employee getEmployeesbyID(Int32 empId)
        {
            Employee employees = new Employee();
            string connectionString = "Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;" +
                   "User ID=scott;Password=ABC54321;Unicode=True";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Emp where EmpNo=" + empId;
                command.CommandText = sql;
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    employees.Employee_ID = empId;
                    employees.Employee_Name = Convert.ToString(reader["EName"]);
                    employees.Employee_Job = Convert.ToString(reader["Job"]);
                }
            }
            return employees;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I developed ASMX web service and used the following code it is giving error on the name of object "Employee" ..Please guide whats the proper code for this task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace WebServiceDemo
{
    public class MyCustomWebService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string getEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            string connectionString = "Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;" + "User ID=scott;Password=ABC54321;Unicode=True";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql;
                sql = "SELECT * FROM Emp where rownum<=100000";
                command.CommandText = sql;
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.Employee_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmpNo"]);
                    employee.Employee_Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Ename"]);
                    employee.Employee_Job = Convert.ToString(reader["Job"]);
                    employees.Add(employee);

                    return (reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Employee class does not exist in the WebServiceDemo namespace.  You'll need to add a reference or an include directive.

Comment: How to add employee class in namespace? But as far as i remember i never included employee class in my WCF service also.